# d3 update circles on line when button clicked

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a chart which should update the data appearance in the chart when a button is clicked.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/264zvtg1/

Somehow the button click won't work in the fiddle but in my sourcecode it works.

Here are the images of the charts.

Before button click:[image]

After button click:
[image]

So the line gets updated and the axis too. But how can the dots on the line move to their new positions and disappear?

Here is how thought the update method should work for the dots:

```
 function weekData() {

     var arr = getDataArr(weekString);
     // Get the data again
     var data = arr.map(function(d) {
         return {
              date: parseDate(d[0]),
              ideal: d[3],
              open: d[1]
         };
     });

       // Scale the range of the data
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
          return d.date;
      }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
          return Math.max(d.open);
      })]);

      xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .ticks(arr.length - 1)
          .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));

     // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
     var svg = d3.select("#area").transition();

     // Make the changes
    svg.select(".openLine")   // change the line
        .duration(750)
        .attr("d", openLine(data))
    svg.select(".dot")
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            if (d.open <= d.ideal) {
                return "#579FAD"
            } else {
                return "#AD6557"
            };
        })
        .attr("cx", function(d){
            return x(d.date);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d){
            return y(d.open);
        })
    svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(-65)"
    });
    svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
        .duration(750)
        .call(yAxis)
 }
```

### **Edit**

Here is a fiddle of my working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jn2mj9wo/1/

Comment: Look in ```enter & exit function()``` : [Update d3js data with button press](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8)

Comment: it says 'svg.selectAll(...).data is not a function' and that is one more thing I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fiddle does what you're after I think: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/a29uguvn/1/

I made a 3 changes to your code:

First, the function you are trying to call via the button with `onclick` is out of scope. To get the button to work in jsfiddle, I replaced your HTML

```
<input name="weekButton" type="button" value="1 week" onclick="weekData()" />
```

with

```
<button id="weekButton">1 week</button>
```

and then defined the event handler like this

```
d3.select('#weekButton').on('click', function () {
  // Update code here
}
```

Second, you were setting the class name `"dot"` for the points before you `append` them

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .attr("class", "dot")
  .enter().append("circle")
```

That meant that the class name wasn't actually being set (and therefore meant that you couldn't select the points later using the class name for updating). Setting the `class` attribute after `append` will do the trick

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "dot")
```

Finally, in in the update function (after button click) you were only selecting the *first* point:

```
svg.select(".dot")
```

This should be:

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
```

to make sure all points are updated

Comment: Having said all that, I'd still recommend looking at the general update pattern (enter / update / exit) as a better way to structure this code. See http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234

Comment: Thank you! I have searched a lot in the web but couldn't find a proper solution for this. I will read the block and try to make more d3 like.